# Is there any emacs mode for checking ELF file

Tags: linux, emacs, elf

I often need to check ELF file(.o, bin and so) by readelf, objdump, nm and some other binutils. I'd like to know if there is any more friendly way to this end. By friendly I mean something like:
fold/unflod of sections 
hyperlink btw symbol and where it's referenced 
interpretation of dwarf information

specific emacs mode for this purpose is most preferable, and any linux/macos tools are also what I seek.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `dwarf-mode.el` in the binutils-gdb tree that offers some pretty display of DWARF with some linking to make navigation easier.  It certainly does not contain all the features you've asked for though, no folding, nor jumping to symbols within the code or data, it's just about DWARF navigation.

You can find it here: https://sourceware.org/git/gitweb.cgi?p=binutils-gdb.git;a=blob_plain;f=binutils/dwarf-mode.el;hb=HEAD

Comment: thank you for your information. dwarf navigation is cool enough. sorry for my late response